# How to strip out redundant packages from 3rd-party libraries in Android?

Tags: java, android, gradle

I have an android app and a *library*, which uses Apache Commons Math.
Apache commons math is quite a fat library and it makes the output apk 1MB bigger.

Since I am only using classes that are related to statistics and interpolation, I have two thoughts of how to reduce the size:

1. I would like to strip out unnecessary packages from the target apk (but how?)
2. The java-library which depends on apache commons can be a fat-jar (its jar-file will i.e. include all classes of apache-commons:math3 in it). I will exclude all unused packages from this jar.
3. ProGuard? - don't want to use this at the moment

The first one seems the easiest, but I still don't know how to write a gradle task that removes unused packages. Any examples or links will be appreciated. :)

Comment: Is there a particular reason you don't want to use ProGuard? It is specifically for stripping unused classes/methods out of your Android app

Answer (score 2):

As for the first option, since it's Apache Commons lib (distributed as open source), you can always create your own fork where you strip it from everything you don't need, recompile and use that recompiled version (make sure to change the version so that you don't accidentally run into any weird problems). Probably not the best solution, though, but worth knowing as a last resort.

Comment: sounds good to me! Actually I haven't thought about it)) thank you